# Python Selenium on Mac: Download Chromedriver not needed anymore?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I recently switched from Windows to Mac and I was wondering why my Selenium script is working without giving it any path to the executable chromedriver file and without downloading any chromedriver executable.

Is that not needed anymore? I also don't find any executable chromedriver file on my whole system. How is that possible? I like it but I would like to understand why that is. If that's the normal behavior, will it also use the correct version of Chromedriver in the future then so that I don't have to use webdriver-manager or download the newest version every time my browser updates anymore?

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

I already searched on the Selenium Website and found that the Getting Startet tutorial also does not define any executable path. Was that ever needed or did it change in the past?

Comment: _I already searched on the Selenium Website and found that the Getting Startet tutorial also does not define any executable path_: _**link**_?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Comment: Does anyone have any idea? I looked for the chromedriver executable on my whole system but can't find it anywhere. It also not in /usr/local/bin . How is it possible that selenium runs without the chromedriver executable on my system? I also set up a fresh venv with only selenium installed and it still worked.